# Write Riak Secondary Index via AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, riak, secondary-indexes

I'm in need of fixing some 2i by hand in Riak 1.4+. I've installed rekon for a sake of use, and now I'm editing template. 
All I want to do is just add some $.ajax onclick like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: $(pairUrl).attr('url'),
type: "POST",
headers: {
    x-riak-index-type_bin: '1'   
},
dataType: 'json' });
```

But it's not working. Is it even possible with jQuery ajax?

Comment: What is the URL? Are you using `/mapred` or `/index`?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear! Url here is taken from Rekon, again, for sake of use. It's always like that: "http://127.0.0.1:8098/buckets/testb/keys/testk". And no, we're not using mapreduce

Comment: In that case, the `type` should be a `PUT`, not `POST`